# Add space before a character with gsub (R)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to add a space before every punctuation character except for `-`and `'`. I don't understand how `\\1` works. This just deletes the dot, while keeping the hyphen and apostrophe.

```
> s<-"I don't play basketball. Covid-19"
> gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]"," \\1", s)
[1] "I don't play basketball  Covid-19"
```

I want to get:

```
I don't play basketball . Covid-19 .
```

Comment: `gsub("([^[:alnum:][:space:]'-])"," \\1", s)`. You forgot to wrap the pattern with a capturing group.

Comment: Where do you get the `.` from at the end of the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, in my original s I had a dot at the end. Yes, it works with a capturing group, thank you!